# What's the easiest way to persist data in an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, persistence

I want to persist a very simple string.  For example "abc".  What's the easiest way to do this?  I don't want to use a SqlLite database.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If it is just one single string NSUserDefaults is probably the easiest way.

```
// write
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"abc" forKey:@"MY_PERSISTENT_KEY"];

// read
NSString *abc = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"MY_PERSISTENT_KEY"];
```

Comment: I only see `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]`.  Perhaps it was changed in a newer SDK since this was first answered?

Comment: Yes, I think in iOS6 there's just standardUserDefaults.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your objects conform to NSCoding, then write them to a file using an NSKeyedArchiver.

```
NSString* path = [self pathForDataFile];
NSMutableDictionary* rootObject = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[rootObject setValue: someObject forKey: @"SomeObject"];

// Commit data to file
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject: rootObject toFile: path];
```